# c# ConsoleApp KeyPressed check

Tags: c#, if-statement, keypress, cycle

I need to check which key is pressed if it is LeftArrow do something, if it is RightArrow do something else, but when none key is pressed the main cycslus must go on.

I have this code for this, but when the proces come to this part it just waiting for key press, it doesnt skip it when none key is pressed. And second porblem is that I need to change position of "*+*" in field by 1, Bud if I left the key pressed long time its move by XXX

```
 if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow)
            {

                int levo;
                levo = pozice;
                if (levo == 1) //Zajištění, že se nedosáhne hodnoty vyšší, než je rozsah pole  
                {
                    levo = levo + 1;
                }
                p18[levo - 1] = "*+*"; //Samotný posun panáčka
                p18[levo] = "   "; //Smazání panáčka z původní pozice

            }


            if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow)
                {

                        int pravo;
                        pravo = pozice;
                        if (pravo == 18) //Zajištění, že se nedosáhne hodnoty vyšší, než je rozsah pole
                        {
                            pravo = pravo - 1;
                        }
                        p18[pravo + 1] = "*+*"; //Samotný posun panáčka
                        p18[pravo] = "   "; //Smazání panáčka z původní pozice

                }
```

Comment: Put `if (Console.KeyAvailable) {}` around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only read the key from the console once per loop and then base the actions on the value read. As the code is written you are reading a new key at each if statement. Below is the modified version of your code that does  this.

```
        var key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;

        if (key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow)
        {
            int levo = pozice;
            if (levo == 1) //Zajištění, že se nedosáhne hodnoty vyšší, než je rozsah pole  
            {
                levo = levo + 1;
            }
            p18[levo - 1] = "*+*"; //Samotný posun panáčka
            p18[levo] = "   "; //Smazání panáčka z původní pozice

        }


        if (key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow)
        {
            int pravo = pozice;
            if (pravo == 18) //Zajištění, že se nedosáhne hodnoty vyšší, než je rozsah pole
            {
                pravo = pravo - 1;
            }
            p18[pravo + 1] = "*+*"; //Samotný posun panáčka
            p18[pravo] = "   "; //Smazání panáčka z původní pozice
        }
```